# Enable inline editing for the Go code in the AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, google-chrome-extension, aws-lambda

As inline code editing is not enabled for the Go code on AWS Lambda, I am trying to create a Google Chrome Extention to be able to edit the Go code by referring to the text or zip code on the S3 bucket. It would be nice if I could also deploy the updated Go code on the Lambda.
I think I will have to perform the following steps from the extension-

1. Get the Go code from the S3 bucket or Github
2. Update it
3. Create a zip file from the updated code
4. Upload the zip file to the S3 bucket or Github
5. Deploy the updated zip file on the Lambda

I have no idea if it is a good approach or if there is any other approach possible for this. I would appreciate it if anyone can suggest to me a better approach or tell me if what I am thinking is feasible or not.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea, but unfortunately I am not sure if that is a good idea.

Let me explain:

All the languages that AWS Lambda supports which allow inline editing are more or less interpreted languages: Javascript, Python etc.

The AWS runtime for those languages reads plain text files and compiles/runs them.

Since you deploy plain text files and the runtime takes care of running them, the AWS Lambda console allows you to edit those files.

Go on the other hand, as well as supported languages like Swift or Java, need to be deployed as a "binary" (I use air quotes because Java JAR is strictly seen not a binary but byte code which is then interpreted by the JVM ..) to AWS.

The AWS Lambda runtime for those languages expects a binary and not plain text. That is why you can not edit the code of Lambdas using those runtimes in the AWS console.

So even if you would open that ZIP, you would not find editable code.

Of course you could put the binary and the plain text code in that ZIP and then when you open that ZIP through your Chrome extension, you could show the plain text code to the user.

But then there is the matter of compiling the code into a binary that the AWS Lambda Go runtime can actually run.

So you Chrome extension would need to bundle a Go compiler. Not sure if that is possible. But I am sure it would not be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have raised some really important points. I will check if the Chrome extension could bundle the Go Compiler.